# Why function binded in tkinter to one button is called when mouse is over another button?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am trying to understand what is happening in my code. There is one function binded to app button and keyboard buttons (enter and numpad enter). I noticed that it behaves strange to me. It runs in loop when I click any other button  (not which it is assigned to) and then move my mouse over next button. I can't spot mistake which I have done. Could you help me please? Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class Gui(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.user_input = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.user_input).grid()
        buttons = self.create_buttons()
        for x in buttons: x.grid()

    def write(self, *_, button=None):
        current = self.user_input.get()
        if button:
            if len(current)<4:
                current += button
        else:
            current = current[:-1]
        self.user_input.set(current)

    def apply(self, *_):
        print(self.user_input.get())

    def create_buttons(self):
        buttons = []
        for x in range(10):
            func = lambda *_, x=x: self.write(button=str(x))
            buttons.append(ttk.Button(self, text=x, command=func))
            self.bind(str(x), func)
        buttons.append(ttk.Button(self, text="Ok", command=self.apply))
        self.bind("<Enter>", self.apply)
        self.bind("<KP_Enter>", self.apply)
        buttons.append(ttk.Button(self, text="<-", command=self.write))
        self.bind("<BackSpace>", self.write)
        return buttons

app = Gui()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `<Enter>` means mouse hovering. If you want to bind key `Enter` then you have to use `<Return>` instead of `<Enter>`.

Comment: BTW: `<Enter>` is mouse hovering, `<Leave>` is mouse unhovering.

Comment: @furas Thank you, I didn't know about hovering. Now everything is working. Can you write it as answer? I will accept it as solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<Enter>` means mouse hovering (mouse enter).
`<Leave>` means mouse unhovering (mouse leave).

If you want to bind key `Enter` then you have to use `<Return>` instead of `<Enter>`

---

Symbols for some keys you can find on effbot.org: [Events and Bindings](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Other keys you can find in Tcl/Tk documentation: [keysyms](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/keysyms.htm)